# Android push notification disappears

Tags: android, notifications

I want to show a notification for an FCM message. Notification is showing good when the app is running, but if the app is not running notification just appears for a second and disappears, even when the user does not click it.

I want my notification to just disappear when user clicks it. 
I was googling and trying use this flag to my notification :

```
defaults = defaults | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
defaults = defaults | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

But that couldn't help, this is my code :

```
    public static void showNotification(Context mContext, Intent resultIntent, String title, String text, String subtext) {
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0,
            resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setTicker(title+" | "+text)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .setSubText(subtext)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    int defaults = 0;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
    mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mNotifyBuilder.build());
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: firebase notification created using default notification format are not shown when app is opened.

Comment: I was created custom service listener, that will call method showNotification() everytime get message from FCM. But the notif auto-dissapears if the app is not opened..

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464684/notification-on-android-device-disappears) answer. If you're connected via USB, a servlet may be grabbing the push notification before you see it on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies here

**PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT**

As official documentation for this flag states that

> Flag indicating that this PendingIntent can be used only once.
>        For use with {@link #getActivity}, {@link #getBroadcast}, and
>        {@link #getService}.
>
> If set, after
>        {@link #send()} is called on it, it will be automatically
>        canceled for you and any future attempt to send through it will fail.

So try replacing this

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0,
        resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

with the following:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, resultIntent, 0);
```

Don't pass any flag in pending intent